# Проблема с API VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Вот смотрите,

```
<?php
$log = "38556555656"; //Это типо номер телефона
$pass = "пароль123"; //это типо пароль
auth($log, $pass); //Вызываю функцию
   function auth($log, $pass){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=тут id приложения&client_secret=тут секретка&username={$log}&password={$pass}');
        $atoken = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $atoken = json_decode($atoken, true);
        print_r($atoken);
    }
?>
```

И когда я его выполняю, то api ВК возвращает мне ошибку:

> Array ( [error] => invalid_client [error_description] => Username or password is incorrect )

Хотя все правильно, а если допустим я стираю вот это

> &username={$log}&password={$pass}
>   и заменяю вот этим
>   &username=38556555656&password=пароль123 , то все нормально. В чем проблема?Я неправильно назначаю переменные что ли?

Comment: Строки в одиночных кавычках не интерполируются.

Comment: @PinkTux зачем вы человека такими словами пугаете? %)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас URL начиная с http:// в одинарных кавычках а переменные например  {$log} или можно просто $log в данном случае интерпретируются только в двойных

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

```
'https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&username='.$log.'&password='.$pass
```